# PHP While loop never finishes Amazon Product API / APAIO?

Tags: php, while-loop, timeout

I've got the following code:

```
$counter = 0;

while($currentPage <= $pages) {
    sleep(0.1);
    flush();
    $browseNodeLookup->setPage($currentPage);
    try {
        $xml = $apaiIO->runOperation($browseNodeLookup);
    } catch(Exception $e1) {
        if($counter == 20) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if($xml) {
        $all_elements =  iq_parse_data($xml, $itemcount, $all_elements);
        $currentPage++;
    } else {
        if($counter == 20) {
            break;
        }
    }
    $counter++;
}
```

By now it looks a little bit weird already, because I just can't get that while loop to break. The problem is, my website suddenly(without any change by myself) crashed. What I did was to just remove the while loop and the website worked again. Now the problem is, sometimes the page loads, and sometimes it doesn't.

When it doesn't the script continues for so long, that with multiple clients, the server crashes and I have to manually restart apache.

Is there anything wrong with this while loop? Did I miss something?

EDIT:

I found out the mistake, it wasn't even about my while loop(allthough the fix with counter <= 20 is also true). It was about guzzle, which makes the request behind "runOperation". I had to define a timeout, because I don't know why, but it seems that something with Amazon Product API changed, so that there could be an infinite loop in guzzle.

The fix was this:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['timeout'  => 2.0]);
```

I should provide the whole code next time, maybe someone would have spotted this. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that your code is not actually hitting your break, because the counter gets incremented every iteration, but you are only checking for exactly 20 when it's not an actual page
The following code should be changed to change this issue:

```
  if($counter >= 20) {
    break;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, you're only breaking when ($counter == 20 && !$xml). You're never advancing $currentPage if that condition isn't true, so the loop will be stuck forever.

Edit for clarity: 
It's likely that $counter has passed 20 by the time that $xml is falsy, which means $currentPage isn't advancing (so your while condition is still true) but because $counter is greater than 20, your break does not get hit. Change `$counter == 20` to `$counter >= 20`.

Also if you're trying to just advance until you either hit 20 or $totalPages, whichever is lower, your code could be simplified to something like

```
$pages = min(20, $pages);

while ($currentPage <= $pages) {
    sleep(0.1);
    flush();

    $browseNodeLookup->setPage($currentPage);

    try {
        $xml = $apaiIO->runOperation($browseNodeLookup);
        $all_elements = iq_parse_data($xml, $itemcount, $all_elements);
    } catch (Exception $e1) {
        // Any error handling you want to do
    }

    $currentPage++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently your code looks a little complicated. You can simplify it in this way:

```
while($currentPage <= $pages) {
    sleep(0.1);
    flush();
    $browseNodeLookup->setPage($currentPage);

    try {
        $xml = $apaiIO->runOperation($browseNodeLookup);
        $all_elements =  iq_parse_data($xml, $itemcount, $all_elements);
    } finally {
        $currentPage++;
    }
}
```